# Angular - mat-sidenav-content does not show up

Tags: html, angular, typescript, mat-sidenav

Currently I try to embed a Sidenav using mat-sidenav-container but the content in mat-sidenav-conent is not shown on the Website (using localhost). The Tutorial im watching does exactly the same and shows the "Main" when loaded. Did I miss something?
The Hello World is shown as usual.

app.component.html

```
<body>
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <mat-sidenav-container>
   <mat-sidenav>Sidenav</mat-sidenav>
   <mat-sidenav-content>Main</mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</body>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'testfile_3';
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatSidenavModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Nope, neither errors nor warnings.

Comment: Okay, I got it. I forgot the BrowserAnimationsModule. Now everything works fine... for now :D